# prevent react-native-webview from opening external apps on its own

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am using **react-native-webview** for my project. However, when I open the website of the e-commerce site, it opens the application of that site by itself.
How can I block it?

I want my application not to open another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**react-native-webview** already provided the solution.

you can try this way.

```
<WebView
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
/>
```

Comment: This works fine in Android, however, iOS still opens my external app. The documentation also states, that it works only on Android: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#setSupportMultipleWindows 
Any suggestions?